# Como adicionar linha vertical em gráfico do tipo coluna

Tags: php, google-charts

Estou utilizando o gráfico de colunas da API Google Chart.

Gostaria de inserir uma linha vertical em uma determinada posição de forma dinâmica.

Tenho um array que indica valor => quantidade. Em um exemplo fictício, seria algo como (5 (nota) => 500 (quantidade de pessoas que acertaram 5)).

Ex.:

```
$arr = array('<=4' => 500, 5 => 500, 6 => 300);
```

Existe uma variavel x, que receberá um valor de 0 a 10, e que deve ser representada no gráfico atráves da linha vertical já mencionada, indicando a posição dentre os outros.

No exemplo da imagem, utilizei `$x = 9` e aloquei em sua respectiva posição.

Então, por fim, ficam as dúvidas:

Como inserir a barra vertical?

Como fazer com que a mesma se posicione de acordo proporcional do eixo X?

[image: Gráfico de colunas - google chart]

**Resultado esperado:**

[image: histograma]

**Código JS + HTML**

```js
    google.charts.load("current", {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ["Element", "Density", {role: 'annotation'}],
            ["<=4", 672, "672"],
            ["5", 648, "648"],
            ["6", 709, "709"],
            ["7", 569, "569"],
            ["8", 459, "459"],
            ["9", 223, "223"],
            ["10", 17, "17"],
        ]);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

        var options = {
            title: "Descrição",
            width: 1159,
            height: 400,
            bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
            legend: {position: "none"},
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("grafico"));
        chart.draw(view, options);
    }
```

```html
<div id="grafico" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Qual seria o motivo de criar essa linha vertical? Não atrapalharia na visualização do gráfico?

Comment: A linha iria servir para indicar, em paralelo com o gráfico, a posição da pessoa em um intervalo de 0 a 10.

Answer (score 3):

Adicione colunas em seu gráfico com a role *annotation* e com isso apenas defina o texto para a linha.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
google.charts.load("current", {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  });
  data.addColumn('number', 'Gatos');
  data.addRow(["A", null, 1]);
  data.addRow(["E", null, 7]);
  data.addRow(["F", null, 7]);
  data.addRow(["G", 'Texto Aqui', 1]);
  data.addRow(["H", null, 4]);


  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("grafico"));
  chart.draw(view, {
    curveType: 'function',
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {
      maxValue: 10
    },
    annotations: {
      style: 'line'
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="grafico" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Caso queira um exemplo maior, pode ver [este fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NC37X/)